# Library conflict in SoapUI

Tags: java, groovy, jar, soapui

My problem is simple :

I created my own jar to use it in a groovy testSuite :

My lib needs  :

`bcpkix-jdk15on-1.49` and `bcprov-ext-jdk15on-159`

In the lib folder in my soapui path I have :

```
bcprov-jdk15-1.46
```

So when I import my jar into a groovy script in soapUI, I get this error :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z error at line: 7
```

Which is probably a conflict in bcprov library, is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Is there already a bcprov JAR in the lib directory? I think SoapUI ships with one. Also, your own JARs should go into the bin/ext directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- Upgrade any existing libraries in soapUI's `lib` directory with your own and put any additional libraries in `bin/ext` and then restart soapUI. If soapUI isn't using specific features of the replaced libraries you could be lucky and it'll just work.
- Otherwise, create your own Groovy or Java project containing your dependencies along with a simple interface to call the functionality you need. Bundle this new project into a JAR and drop it into `bin/ext` and restart soapUI. You should then be able to call your interface from within soapUI through a Groovy script.