# Read from excel file and load into SOAP UI request

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I am pretty new to Java and Groovy . However ,I have a requirement to read data from a excel file and load them into a SOAPUI test suite . I followed a few links from google and tried to implement the same but facing error .

I have downloaded POI 4.1.0 jars and copied them to SOAPUI/bin/ext folder .In SOAPUI , I have added a step for groovy script(mentioned below).

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*                                                  
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*

impot org.apache.poi.ss.util.*


def fs = new FileInputStream("FILE LOCATION")

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);

def ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1")

def r = ws.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()

log.info "==========="+r
```

It should return me the number of rows .But I am getting an error instead .

```
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: Could not initialize calss org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader    Error at line 7
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what contents are you reading from excel and where / how loading in test suite?

Comment: **Exactly** which files did you copy into `bin/ext`? If you get the "Binary Distribution" from https://poi.apache.org/download.html and open that, you will notice there are multiple dependencies (included). Some of these are possibly going to conflict with that is already provided with SoapUI.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of these types of errors on the SmartBear forums and in other places, but not many consistent resolutions across versions of soapUI and POI. Your code works when run outside of soapUI suggesting there's some sort of JAR version conflict between soapUI and POI.

So, there are a couple of options:

- If you can afford it, SoapUI Pro has Excel functionality built into it's data loop test steps.
- Try down-grading to an earlier version of POI and soapUI. Code essentially the same as yours [worked with soapUI 5.3 and POI 3.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028465/is-there-a-limitation-reading-xlsx-file-using-soapui-free-version-5-3-0-apache)
- Use something simpler. Since you're using Excel, you should be able to get your data as CSV and use something like [public Object splitEachLine(String regex, Closure closure)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#splitEachLine(java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) to process CSV data using only Groovy.
- Create your own Groovy or Java project containing the POI dependencies along with a simple interface to call the functionality you need. See for example, [Library conflict in SoapUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688896/library-conflict-in-soapui)

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that works well with .xls files (Have issues with .xlsx files though).

First Download jxl.jar to access excel files via Groovy script. Source: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi.

Download the latest version (Current version: 2.6.12). Unzip the file, copy the JXL.jar to both:

```
Contents/java/app/bin/ext
Contents/java/app/lib
```

Now add a Test Step -> Properties and declare the data to be read as variables (property1, property2).

Use the script in the Groovy Script Test step (Added functionality to write the response results into another excel file):

```
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import jxl.write.Number

// Specify the path to the input Excel File
def inpFile = new File("path/inputFile.xls")

// Specify the path to the output Excel File
def outFile = new File("path/outputFile.xls")
// Create a workbook object for the input Excel file
Workbook inpWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inpFile)
// Get the sheet containing the property values, 1st sheet here
Sheet propSheet = inpWorkbook.getSheet(0)
// Get no of rows
def numRows = propSheet.getRows()
// Create Workbook obj for output Excel File
WritableWorkbook outWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(outFile)
// Create a "Res" sheet for results
Writable resSheet = outWorkbook.createSheet("Res", 0)

// Create labels for the result
def label = new Label(0, 0, "Test Step")
resSheet.addCell(label)
def label = new Label(1, 0, "Status")
resSheet.addCell(label)

// Loop through each row of the sheet containing data to be read
for (i in 1..numRows-1) {
    // Read the property values from current row of excel sheet 
    // 1st column has nodeVal1, 2nd column has nodeVal2
    def property1 = propSheet.getCell(0, i).getContents()
    def property2 = propSheet.getCell(1, i).getContents()
    
    // Get the test case and test step
    def testCase = testRunner.testCase
    def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
    def testRequestStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("test_request name")
   
    // Set property values for the test step
    testStep.setPropertyValue("property1", property1)
    testStep.setPropertyValue("property2", property2)

    // Execute the test request
    testRequestStep.run(testRunner, context)

    // Get the SOAP response of the test request
    def resp = testRequestStep.testRequest.response

    // Create a cell for the test step
    def cell = new Label(0, i, testRequestStep.name)
    resSheet.addCell(cell)
    // Create columns for retrieving response Node values
    cell = new Label(2, 0, "Node Val1")
    resSheet.addCell(cell)
    cell = new Label(3, 0, "Node Val2")
    resSheet.addCell(cell)

    if (resp.responseHeaders.toString().contains("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")) {
        label = new Label(1, i, "Pass")
        resSheet.addCell(label)
        def xmlResp = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response.getContentAsString())
        // NodeName1 and NodeName2 are the reqd nodes from the successful response
        def nodeVal1 = xmlResp.'**'.find { it.name() == 'NodeName1' }?.text()
        def nodeVal2 = xmlResp.'**'.find { it.name() == 'NodeName2' }?.text()
        cell = new Label(2, i, nodeVal1)
        resSheet.addCell(cell)
        cell = new Label(3, i, nodeVal2)
        resSheet.addCell(cell)
    } else if (resp.responseHeaders.toString().contains("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error")) {
        label = new Label(1, i, "Fail")
        resSheet.addCell(label)
    }
}
// Write and close the Workbooks
outWorkbook.write()
outWorkbook.close()
inpWorkbook.close()
```

You can modify the script to check for various response types.